# Running NGINX project on Windows with laravel framework

Tags: php, laravel, nginx, webserver, homestead

I want to run my `NGINX` project on Windows using `laravel` framework. But trying to do that I only find tutorials about either how to connect `laravel` with `NGINX` on `Ubuntu` or installing `laravel` framework on Windows with `xampp server`. Is it possible to use `NGINX + Laravel` on Windows? I've come up with an idea of using Homestead as it includes `NGINX` and `laravel` framework and can be used with `Vagrant and VirtualBox` on windows. However, I've never seen someone running actual `laravel` project on `NGINX` and not `xampp` on Windows. Any workarounds concerning Homestead?

Answer (score 0):

Homestead should work fine on Windows, just make sure you convert any Linux style paths to windows format (ie C:)

Answer (score 0):

It is possible using [WinNMP](https://winnmp.wtriple.com) - Nginx MariaDB Redis Php 7 development stack for Windows. It is very fast and stable and has composer and command line support.

First, install the WinNMP stack, then follow their guide about how to [Create a new LARAVEL Project](https://winnmp.wtriple.com/howtoFrameworks).

It shows you how to run `composer`, how to create a Local Virtual Server and how to configure Nginx rewrite rules for Laravel.